# flutter list pagination not stable

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, pagination

I'm trying to do pagination on a list that gets its items from an HTTP request

here is the request function

```
final baseURL = 'http://vlaw.thefuturevision.com:5000/api';

Future<List<LawFirm>> getLawFirms ({required BuildContext context, required Map<String, dynamic>? filter}) async {
print('request filter: $filter');
d.Dio dio = d.Dio();
final response = await dio.get('$baseURL/law-firm',
    queryParameters: filter).catchError((onError) {
  throw AppLocalizations.of(context)!.unable_to_connect;
});
if(response.statusCode == 200) {
  var dynamicResponse = response.data;
  var dynamicLawFirms = dynamicResponse['data'];
  List<Map<String,dynamic>> maps = List<Map<String,dynamic>>.from(dynamicLawFirms);
  for (var element in maps) {
    LawFirm lawFirm = LawFirm();
    lawFirm.id = element['_id'];
    lawFirm.nameAR = element['nameAr'];
    lawFirm.nameEN = element['nameEn'];
    if(element.containsKey('specialty')) {
      lawFirm.speciality = element['specialty'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('city')) {
      lawFirm.city = element['city'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('specialty')) {
      lawFirm.speciality = element['specialty'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('website')) {
      lawFirm.website = element['website'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('facebook')) {
      lawFirm.facebook = element['facebook'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('twitter')) {
      lawFirm.twitter = element['twitter'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('instagram')) {
      lawFirm.instagram = element['instagram'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('whatsapp')) {
      lawFirm.whatsApp = element['whatsapp'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('fax')) {
      lawFirm.fax = element['fax'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('pobox')) {
      lawFirm.poBox = element['pobox'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('email')) {
      lawFirm.email = element['email'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('descriptionAr')) {
      lawFirm.descriptionAR = element['descriptionAr'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('descriptionEn')) {
      lawFirm.descriptionEN = element['descriptionEn'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('locationAr')) {
      lawFirm.addressAR = element['locationAr'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('locationEn')) {
      lawFirm.addressEN = element['locationEn'];
    }
    if(element.containsKey('longLat')) {
      LongLat longLat = LongLat();
      var dynamicLongLat = element['longLat'];
      longLat.type = dynamicLongLat['type'];
      longLat.coordinates = List<dynamic>.from(dynamicLongLat['coordinates']);
      lawFirm.longLat = longLat;
    }
    if(element.containsKey('workingDays')) {
      var dynamicWorkingDays = element['workingDays'] as List;
      dynamicWorkingDays.forEach((element) {
        WorkingDay workingDay = WorkingDay();
        workingDay.day = element['day'];
        workingDay.closingHour = element['closingHour'];
        workingDay.openingHour = element['openingHour'];
        lawFirm.workingDays = [];
        lawFirm.workingDays?.add(workingDay);
      });
    }
    if(element.containsKey('employees')) {
      lawFirm.employees = List<Employee>.from(element['employees']);
    }
    if(element.containsKey('images')) {
      lawFirm.images = List<Image>.from(element['images']);
    }
    lawFirm.mobile = element['mobile'];
    lawFirm.phone = element['phone'];
    _lawFirms.add(lawFirm);
  }
  notifyListeners();
  return _lawFirms;
}
throw AppLocalizations.of(context)!.unable_to_connect;
  }
```

and here is how I manage the pagination

```
_lawFirmListController.addListener(() {
  if (_lawFirmListController.position.extentAfter < 500) {
    _lawFirms.then((value) {
      Map<String,dynamic> lawFirmFilter = {
        'total': true, //to get total items in the response body
        'limit': 10, //items per request
        'skip': value.length
      };
      Provider.of<ApiServices>(context, listen: false).getLawFirms(context: context, filter: lawFirmFilter);
      _lawFirms.then((value) => print('list length is: ${value.length}'));
    });
  }
});
```

I'm using `list.builder` to view the items and here's how I view the list

```
_lawFirms = _apiServices.getLawFirms(context: context, filter: _lawFirmsFilter);

_buildLawFirms() => Consumer<ApiServices>(
builder: (consumerContext, _, child) => FutureBuilder(
  future: _lawFirms,
  builder: (BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<List<LawFirm>> snapshot) {
    late Widget animatedSwitcherChild;
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      animatedSwitcherChild =
      const CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 2, color: Colors.black);
    }
    else if(snapshot.hasData){
      if(snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
        animatedSwitcherChild = Center(child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.no_law_firms));
      }
      else {
        animatedSwitcherChild = ListView.builder(
          controller: _lawFirmListController,
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return InkWell(
                child: LawFirmWidget(lawFirm: snapshot.data![index]),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              LawFirmById(id: snapshot.data![index].id!)));
                },
              );
            });
      }
    }
    else if(snapshot.hasError){
      animatedSwitcherChild = Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                      primary: Colors.black,
                      fixedSize: const Size(150, 60)
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _lawFirms = _apiServices.getLawFirms(context: context, filter: _lawFirmsFilter);
                  },
                  child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.try_again)
              )
            ]
        ),
      );
    }
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      child: animatedSwitcherChild,
      transitionBuilder: (child, animation) {
        return SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.2),
            end: Offset.zero,
          ).animate(animation),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  },
),
```

);

The problem is that the list duplicates items on a slow scroll and sometimes does not get all items when reaching the end of the pagination.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add the listview full code

Comment: @IonicFireBaseApp listview full code added